# Android 4.2 SDK Libraries don't contain all attrs and styles

Tags: android, android-library

I use ActionBarSherlock in my app, and have referenced some of it's styles and attributes in my app as well to do things like reuse standard android themes and the like.

After updating to the 4.2 SDK and the newest tools (v21) I get compile errors from ant when I try to use those attributes, presumably because of this change:

> Updated the build to generate R resource classes for library projects with only the IDs needed by the libraries, reducing the risk of hitting DEX file limits for fields and methods.
>   http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html

I think, because ABS itself does not reference the attributes and styles I'm using, they are no longer packaged with the library and so they're not there for my "main" project to use.

IntelliJ IDEA compiles everything just fine - but I assume that's because it doesn't know about the new tools yet. Of course, that's not too helpful because my normal process uses an ant script which IDEA runs.

Comment: one more reason to use intellij

Comment: I used to use IntelliJ, but with Ant I can fire off one command and get testing, staging, and release apks out the other end.

Comment: works for me. i did `android update project -p . -t 21 --subprojects` and it updated all my projects to target Google APIs 4.2 and `ant debug` worked just fine.

Comment: Are you using ABS attrs or styles in your code?

Comment: yep. all over the place. i'm extending the themes and i reference the abs styles (and at least 1 drawable)

Comment: I've tried again today, but running that command does not work. I verified that 21 is the support API, removed the gen/ folders.. but still get the compile errors.